# Display incoming video/audio call screen in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, webrtc

I am integrating RTC based audio/video calling feature in my flutter app. For now I am using FCM for push notifications. How can I display incoming call notification and screen like skype & whatsapp on my app when it is closed or in background.

Comment: Dis u find any solution to this?